# Численное интегрирование в питоне

Tags: python, математика

Привет. Мне необходимо сделать программу вычисления определённого интеграла sin(x)/x с приделами интегрирования от 1 до 10. Нужно решить методом прямоугольников (левых) с точностью 0,001.

[image: Формула]
[image: Написано более понятно]

Шаг разбиения вычисляется так: h = (b - a) / n
где a и b = 1 и 10, n = количество разбиений (сначала 2, потом 4, 8, 16...).
Код нужно будет объяснить СИшнику, который в глаза не видел питон, поэтому желательно сделать максимально по "сишному". Вот написал примерный алгоритм на питоне3, но он выдаёт непредсказуемый результат. Когда онлайн калькулятор выводит 0.71. Спасибо

```
from math import sin
import numpy as np


def func(x):
    return sin(x) / x

n = 2   # Текущая точность
a = 1
b = 10
Si = []
print("Интегрируемая функция: f(x) = sin(x) / x")
print("Точность: 0.001")


def work(n):
    xi = []     # массив с точками разбиений
    print("Текущее число разбиений", n)
    h = (b - a)/n   # Шаг
    print("Текущий шаг: ", h)
    for x in np.arange(a, b, h):    # заносим в массив xi текущие точки для разбиения
        xi.append(func(x))
    print("Значения выбранных точек: ", xi)
    sum = 0
    for i in xi:
        sum += h * func(i)
    tmp_otvet = h * sum     # вычисление по формуле левых прямоугольниках
    print("Текущий результат: ", tmp_otvet)
    if n == 2:          # Если запустили в первый раз, то точность не высчитываем
        Si.append(tmp_otvet)    # В список Si скапливаем результаты вычислений
        work(4)     # запускаем рекурсию
    else:
        if abs(Si[-1] - tmp_otvet) < 0.001:     # если необходимая точность достигнута, то выводим ответ
            otvet(tmp_otvet, n)
        else:
            Si.append(tmp_otvet)    # Иначе запускаем рекурсию с увеличенным вдвое числом разбиений
            work(n * 2)


def otvet(S, n):
    print("___________")
    print("Результат: ", S)
    print("Число разбиений: ", n)
    exit(0)

work(2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from math import sin


def work(f, a, b, n):
    print("\nТекущее число разбиений: ", n)
    h = (b-a)/float(n)
    print("Текущий шаг:", h)
    total = sum([f((a + (k*h))) for k in range(0, n)])
    result = h * total
    print("Текущий результат: ", result)
    return result


def f(x):
    return sin(x)/x

print("Используем формулу левых прямоугольников")
print("Интегрируемая функция: f(x) = sin(x) / x")
print("Точность: 0.001")

n = 2
a1 = work(f, 1, 10, n)
n *= 2
a2 = work(f, 1, 10, n)

while abs(a1 - a2) > 0.001:
    n *= 2
    a1 = work(f, 1, 10, n)
    n *= 2
    a2 = work(f, 1, 10, n)

print("\nОтвет:", a2, "\nКоличество разбиений:", n)
```